# Drive 230Vac load (bulb,fan etc) using microcontroller (3.3V or 5V)

Tags: design

i want to drive the the lights and fan used in home(230Vac/50Hz) using digital circuitry.
so kindly suggest me the best one.
1. using micro-controller i want to actuate the loads like Bulb,incandescent lights and also their dimmer action
2.drive fan and also control its speed.

Basically i have done it using the flow as shown
microcontroller to opto-coupler to transistor(BC547B) to relay.
but i came to know that the relay switching efficiency is poor due to which fluctuations in switching of Lights and bulb is observed.
so kindly suggest me some more sofisticated circuit to drive the loads as i want to design this circuit and implement in my home.

Comment: Some people may have trouble following this (strangely). It is clear and a useful question.

Answer (score 1):

For home automation, you should look into X10:

http://www.x10.com/homepage.htm

X10 interfaces exist to automate just about any part of a house. To control the automation, you can use one of the dedicated X10 panels or implement the X10 protocol on your microcontorller of choice. There are plenty of libraries available for PIC, AVR, 8051, etc.